# how to reduce time of a query which have 4 joins

Tags: mysql, join

I am new to CakePHP and I am working on CakePHP 3.8 version. There is a join query which takes almost 10 -12 seconds to fetch data. I don't know how to optimize this query. this query is written in CakePHP 3.8 format.

```
SELECT Coach.email                AS `Coach__email`, 
       Coach.name                 AS `Coach__name`, 
       Coach.account_id           AS `Coach__account_id`, 
       Coach.id                   AS `Coach__id`, 
       Coach.last_login           AS `Coach__last_login`, 
       Coach.subscription         AS `Coach__subscription`, 
       Coach.linked_agency        AS `Coach__linked_agency`, 
       A.name                     AS `A__name`, 
       Find_in_set(2, U.activate) AS `active`, 
       ( Count(C.id) )            AS `count`, 
       ( Count(CA.id) )           AS `countactive` 
FROM   jsb_coach Coach 
       INNER JOIN jsb_accounts U 
               ON U.id = Coach.account_id 
       LEFT JOIN jsb_client C 
              ON C.coach_id = Coach.account_id 
       LEFT JOIN jsb_client CA 
              ON CA.id = C.id 
                 AND CA.status LIKE 1 
       LEFT JOIN jsb_agency A 
              ON Coach.agency_id = A.account_id 
GROUP  BY Coach.id 
ORDER  BY Coach.last_login DESC
```

Comment: Please provide information from the explain and table creation script so that we can get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: A quick note, you shouldn't use a LIKE condition when you are using an exact match

Comment: @JoeW actually in that I have many commas separated value. and plz check the link http://cmsbox.in/app/Capture.PNG

Comment: You should add that to the question as text if possible instead of a picture so that the text is searchable. Also if you are using bind variables as part of the query you should include the bind variable or an example of it to provide a better idea. However that being said based on the little information we it seems like using a LIKE operator on a status field is a bad idea as you should be able to do an exact match easily since all statuses should be known

Comment: Remove the `GROUP BY` to see if it gets the same answer.  If not then read about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to understand that the results are indeterminate.